# Responsive CSS Caption | Mouse Over Image

Tags: html, css

I would like to show caption on mouse over image – but on mobile, the caption should positioned below the image. Any ideas? http://jsfiddle.net/X8eCV/2/

```
@media (max-width:600px) {

#caption
{
display:block;
}

}
#caption {
 position:relative;
color:red;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `position:relative` to `#image`

```
@media screen and (max-width:600px) {
    #caption {
        position:relative;
        color:red;
    }

    #image {
        position:relative;
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dvdyakonov/X8eCV/11/

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/X8eCV/3/) one:

```
@media (max-width:600px) {
    #caption {
        display:block; /* <-- */
        position:relative;
        color:red;
    }
}
```

Okay, here is how I would do this:

http://jsfiddle.net/X8eCV/2/

Comment: Yes, but the caption should @media 600px below the image.

Answer (score -1):

http://jsfiddle.net/X8eCV/10/

```
  @media screen and (max-width:600px) {
#caption {
    position:relative;
 top:200px;
    color:red;
   }
  }
```